# Examples of 3d CNN in tensorflow. InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to change the cifar10 example to realize 3d CNN.
But there seems to be other things I should change excepte for the convolution and pooling.
When I only changed the convolution layer, pool layer and the input, I got the following error. Is there any suggestion on what should I do, or are there any examples? 
Thanks.

```
 File "/mnt/disk1/Fu/Function/Tensorflow/Test/cifar10.py", line 152, in distorted_inputs
    batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
  File "/mnt/disk1/Fu/Function/Tensorflow/Test/cifar10_input.py", line 125, in distorted_inputs
    shuffle = False)
  File "/mnt/disk1/Fu/Function/Tensorflow/Test/cifar10_input.py", line 88, in _generate_image_and_label_batch
    tf.image_summary('images', images)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/logging_ops.py", line 151, in image_summary
    tag=tag, tensor=tensor, max_images=max_images, name=scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 161, in _image_summary
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [20,32,32,32,1]
         [[Node: ImageSummary = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor<type: uint8 shape: [4] values: 255 0 0...>, max_images=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ImageSummary/tag, batch)]]
         [[Node: local4/weight_loss/_104 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_48_local4/weight_loss", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](local4/weight_loss)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the image summary to support 3d images as well (or, more easily, remove it from your graph).

Comment: any idea how to change the image summary to support 3d images as well?

Comment: I think the standard image summary does not support 3d images, and you'll need to write a tensorboard plugin. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard-plugin-example/blob/master/README.md for more instructions on how to do that, but it's a nontrivial amount of work.